# Php mysqli : update user where amount is less then x and delete query

Tags: php, mysqli

this one, it does delete where amount is less then 1 
but it doesnt update user, why not? can anyone tell me?

```
$data1 = mysqlI_query($link,"SELECT * FROM bubble_spends where burst <= 0");
$data  = mysqli_fetch_array($data1);

$burst123='$data[burst]';
$username123='$data[username]';
IF($data1)
{
    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE * FROM 'users' SET 'bitcoins'='bitcoins'-'$burst123' WHERE 'username' = '$username123' ");
    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM bubble_spends where amount <= 1");
}
```

Greets Patrick

Answer (score 0):

1. Update query syntax is wrong, correct query

UPDATE `users` SET `bitcoins`=`bitcoins`- $burst123 WHERE `username` = '$username123'

2. Remove single quote(') from table and column name and use tick(`) instead. e.g. UPDATE * FROM 'users' SET 'bitcoins'='bitcoins'-'$burst123' WHERE 'username' = '$username123'
3. You are using this '$burst123' which is treated as string.

**Updated Query :**

```
$data1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM bubble_spends where burst <= 0");
$data  = mysqli_fetch_array($data1);

$burst123='$data[burst]';
$username123='$data[username]';
IF($data1)
{
    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `users` SET `bitcoins`=`bitcoins`- $burst123 WHERE `username` = '$username123' ");
    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM bubble_spends where amount <= 1");
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work
i really try'd alot
there are no output error's

Comment: in your update query you are using single quote around table and column name, like 'users' which is not right you have to use `users`.

Comment: try'd it without ' also.

Comment: `echo mysqli_error($link); exit;` after update query. and show me what error you are getting

Comment: still no error..

<code>
IF($data1)
{
    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE * FROM `users` SET `bitcoins`=`bitcoins`- $burst123 WHERE `username` = '$username123' ");
    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM bubble_spends where amount <= 1");
} ELSE { echo mysqli_error($link); exit;}    </code>

Comment: mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE * FROM users SET bitcoins=bitcoins- $burst123 WHERE username = '$username123' "); echo mysqli_error($link); exit; use like this for debugging

Comment: have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM users SET bitcoins=bitcoins- $data[burst] WHERE username = '$data[usernam' at line 1

Comment: i try'd this now.
$burst123=$data['burst'];
$username123=$data['a_username'];


IF($data1)
{
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE users SET bitcoins=bitcoins-$burst123 WHERE username = $username123"); echo mysqli_error($link); exit;  
    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM bubble_spends where amount <= 1");
}

because username is a double variable . i made from bubble_spends username changed to a_username. didnt work

Comment: UPDATE T1
SET T1.Address = T2.New_Address
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID


i am trying to make this work now. but it isnt easy.

Comment: try this, 

$data1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM bubble_spends where burst <= 0");
$data  = mysqli_fetch_array($data1);

$burst123='$data[burst]';
$username123='$data[username]';
IF($data1)
{
    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `users` SET `bitcoins`=`bitcoins`- $burst123 WHERE `username` = '$username123' ");
    mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM bubble_spends where amount <= 1");
}